# Ajax request is red and isnt sending data to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Trying to send parameters to mysql with ajax and php?I've done this before in my project but this isn't working for some reason

View :

```
$(document).on('click','#btnbehvoegtoe',function(){

            var klacht = $('#lijstbeh_klacht').val();
            var diagnose = $('#lijstbeh_diagnose').val();
            var beh = $('#lijstbeh_behandeling').val();
            var behkort = $('#lijstbeh_behandelingkort').val();
            alert(patid);
            alert(klacht + diagnose + beh + behkort);



            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'behandelingen/addbehandeling',
                datatype : 'JSON',
                data: { BEH_PA_ID : patid,
                        BEH_klacht : klacht,
                        BEH_diagnose : diagnose,
                        BEH_behandeling : beh,
                        BEH_behandelingkort : behkort
                },
                success : function(){
                    alert("De behandeling is toegevoegd");
                }
            });
        });
```

Controller

```
public function addbehandeling()
{
    $this->load->model('behandelingen_model');
    $this->behandelingen_model->addbehandeling();

}
```

Model

```
function addbehandeling()
{
$BEH_PA_ID = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('BEH_PA_ID'));
$BEH_klacht = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('BEH_klacht'));
$BEH_diagnose = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('BEH_diagnose'));
$BEH_behandeling = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('BEH_behandeling'));
$BEH_behandelingkort = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('BEH_behandelingkort'));
$data = array(
            'BEH_PA_ID' => $BEH_PA_ID,
            'BEH_klacht' => $BEH_klacht,
            'BEH_diagnose' => $BEH_diagnose,
            'BEH_behandeling' => $BEH_behandeling,
            'BEH_behandelingkort' => $BEH_behandelingkort,
            'BEH_datum' => date('Y-m-d')
);
$this -> db -> insert('behandelingen', $data);

}
```

The alerts work 
Firebug has the parameters as POST aswell

Comment: You shouldn't prematurely sanitize data. In this case, you do something called `xss_clean` and then try to input this data in an SQL insert.
Only encode those strings on *output*, not on input. And what is the error you get?

Comment: try this in the controller `public function actionaddbehandeling()`

Comment: Changed it, no effect

Comment: When your ajax request is red, it probably failed. What status code is in the response?

Comment: nothing, thats my main issue

Comment: You are not passing the posted data into the model